# Cannot convert value of type '(String!, NSError!) -> ()' to expected argument type 'GGLInstanceIDTokenHandler!'

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I have this problem with `Google Cloud Messaging` (`GCM`) after refactoring to Swift 3. Can anyone help?

I got this error: 
**Cannot convert value of type '(String!, NSError!) -> ()' to expected argument type 'GGLInstanceIDTokenHandler!'**

Here:

```
func application( _ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data ) {

// ...

GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler) 
}
```

And same error here:

```
func onTokenRefresh() {
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().token(withAuthorizedEntity: gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
}
```

This is the registrationHandler:

```
func registrationHandler(_ registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
    // ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the signature of `registrationHandler` has changed. Retype the method(s) to get the actual signature with code completion.

Comment: @vadian: it show the registrationHandler is depricated :(

Comment: Then look in the documentation for the replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change registrationHandler to

```
func registrationHandler(_ registrationToken: String?, error: Error?) {
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

David's answer doesn't work with Swift 3, unfortunately. However, this does:

```
func registrationHandler(registrationToken: Optional<String>, error: Optional<Error>) {
    // ...
}
```